# load image gallery using fancybox3 via AJAX request

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, fancybox

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web page with an image gallery. I am trying to get the "large image" to load asynchronously with an AJAX call, since the page would take too long to load if I were to load my large images upfront.

Here's what I have in my view:

```
@{
    string srcMain = "";
}

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.7/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function getLargeImage(imageID, imageType) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Explore/GetLargeImage?i=" + imageID + "&objectType=" + imageType,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                return data;
            }
        })
    }

</script>


...

foreach (var item in Model.Image.ExhibitionImages)
{
    <div class="tile-outer">
        <div class="tile-inner">
            @if (item.Image_MimeType_MediumPad != null)
            {
                srcMain = "data:" + item.Image_MimeType_MediumPad + ";base64," + @Html.Raw(Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image_Data_MediumPad));

                <a data-fancybox="gallery" data-type="ajax" data-src="getLargeImage(@item.ID, @Model.Image.Type);" href="javascript:;">
                    <img src="@srcMain" id="@anchorID" class="tile-image" alt="Image" />
                </a>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}

...
```

Here is the JsonResult in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetLargeImage(int i, int objectType)
{
    var imageResult = LoadSP_ImageLarge("sp_ImageLarge", i, objectType);
    List<ImageLarge> list_ImageLarge = new List<ImageLarge>();
    foreach (var row in imageResult)
    {
        list_ImageLarge.Add(new ImageLarge
        {
            Image_Data_string = (row.Image_Data != null) ? string.Format("data:" + row.Image_MimeType + ";base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(row.Image_Data)) : null
        });
    }
    string imageString = list_ImageLarge.FirstOrDefault().Image_Data_string;

    return Json(imageString, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I am following the fancybox3 template for [loading content via AJAX](https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#ajax) - pasted below:

```
<a data-fancybox data-type="ajax" data-src="my_page.com/path/to/ajax/" href="javascript:;">
    AJAX content
</a>
```

I put a breakpoint on the JsonResult method in my controller, and the cursor never enters it, so I am doing something wrong in my effort to call the method. Does anyone see my mistake? I am confused about how to adapt the example code `data-src="my_page.com/path/to/ajax/"` to my existing code. It seems to not like my javascript function call: `data-src="getLargeImage(@item.ID, @Model.Image.Type);"` What should I be doing differently?

Comment: To load the large image on-demand, you don't need to use ajax.Fancybox send the request to Large Image Url after you clicked on the small image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load the large image on-demand, you don't need to use ajax. Having tags like this:

```
<a id="id" href="Large Image Url"><img src="Small Image Url"/></a>
```

Fancybox send the request to Large Image Url after you clicked on the small image.

You just need set it up:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#id").fancybox({ type: 'image' });
});
```

**Example**

The following example shows a minimal example that loads the large image on-demand. The example assumes you read images from the following urls:

- Large: `/gallery/getlargeimage/{id}` - The server handles how to load images
- Small: `/gallery/getsmallimage/{id}` - The server handles how to load images

> If you expose direct link to the images, you even don't need need
>   actions to handle small and large images. The example is just for
>   learning purpose to show how you can return an image from an action.

**GalleryController**

```
public class GalleryController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult GetLargeImage(int id)
    {
        //Load the large image from filesystem or database 
        var file = Server.MapPath($@"/Images/Large/{id}.jpg");
        return File(file, @"image/jpeg");
    }
    public ActionResult GetSmallImage(int id)
    {
        //Load the large image from filesystem or database 
        var file = Server.MapPath($@"/Images/Small/{id}.jpg");
        return File(file, @"image/jpeg");
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{Layout = null;}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Gallery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
        href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a#example1").fancybox({ type: 'image' });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a id="example1" href="/gallery/getlargeimage/1">
            <img alt="example1" src="/gallery/getsmallimage/1" />
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Post Actions in MVC get their arguments from the message body, not the URI. So, you would have to do something like this:

```
    function getLargeImage(imageID, imageType) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetLargeImage", "Explore")",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ i: imageID, objectType: imageType }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                return data;
            }
        });
    }
```